# VSCode Remote-SSH could not establish connection to "host"

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote-ssh

I am working on a project that resides on a remote SSH server and I am trying to use Remote-SSH to work on the project in a local VS Code session. However, I am not able to work it out. When connecting to a host "host" after jumpy from a proxy, the error message appears as

> Could not establish connection to "host"

My config file looks like this:

```
Host proxy
    HostName proxyipaddress
    User username
    IdentityFile pathtokey
Host host
    HostName hostipaddress
    User username
    ProxyJump proxy
```

The following output is shown in the output tab:

```
[12:23:41.051] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+host", attempt 1
[12:23:41.053] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[12:23:41.055] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[12:23:41.057] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"proxy":"linux"}
[12:23:41.057] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[12:23:41.058] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[12:23:41.058] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[12:23:41.058] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[12:23:41.058] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[12:23:41.059] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[12:23:41.059] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[12:23:41.059] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[12:23:41.060] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[12:23:41.060] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[12:23:41.060] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[12:23:41.061] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[12:23:41.061] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[12:23:41.074] VS Code version: 1.79.2
[12:23:41.074] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.102.0
[12:23:41.074] win32 x64
[12:23:41.076] SSH Resolver called for host: host
[12:23:41.076] Setting up SSH remote "host"
[12:23:41.081] Using commit id "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" and quality "stable" for server
[12:23:41.089] Install and start server if needed
[12:23:44.037] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssh.exe -V"
[12:23:44.049] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssh.exe ENOENT
[12:23:44.051] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\ssh.exe -V"
[12:23:44.056] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\ssh.exe ENOENT
[12:23:44.056] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe -V"
[12:23:44.059] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe ENOENT
[12:23:44.059] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe -V"
[12:23:44.061] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe ENOENT
[12:23:44.061] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
[12:23:44.124] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5

[12:23:44.129] Running script with connection command: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 54966 "host" bash
[12:23:44.142] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[12:23:44.441] > CreateProcessW failed error:2
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[12:23:44.441] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[12:23:44.449] > posix_spawn: No such file or directory
> The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[12:23:45.751] "install" terminal command done
[12:23:45.752] Install terminal quit with output: ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exeposix_spawn: No such file or directory
[12:23:45.752] Received install output: ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exeposix_spawn: No such file or directory
[12:23:45.753] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[12:23:45.756] Resolver error: Error: 
    at m.Create (c:\Users\ua\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:584145)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\ua\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:582705)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\ua\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:681881)
    at async c:\Users\ua\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:644110
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\ua\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:647428)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\ua\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:645160)
    at async c:\Users\ua\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.102.0\out\extension.js:1:720916
[12:23:45.768] ------
```

**Notes**

1. I have connected to the proxy and that works perfectly without issues.
2. I have checked for disk usage on the host and that is not a problem.
3. I have killed the server and downloaded it again but that doesn't work either.